# Random Non Repeating Number Generation Assignment to Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, random, shuffle

I'm attempting to generate non repeating random numbers between 1-5, 1-10, 1-20, etc. I'm on to the Fisher-Yates Shuffle but I'm not sure I've implemented it in the best way. My plan is to associate each random number to a predetermined variable name. I want to make sure the syntax is correct for assignment of the random values to predetermined variable names.  I'm new to JavaScript and would appreciate any insight. Here's my first rendition:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        j = 0,
        temp;

    while (i--) {

        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));

        
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;

    }

    return array;
}

var ranNums = shuffle([1,2,3,4,5]);

var ranNum1 = ranNums.value;    
var ranNum2 = ranNums.value;    
var ranNum3 = ranNums.value;    
var ranNum4 = ranNums.value;
var ranNum5 = ranNums.value;
```

Comment: If your code is working, and you want general feedback on it (a "code review"), please post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. If your code is not working, please edit your question to clearly state what isn't working, and any error messages you are getting.

Comment: The part of your question that says *I'm on to the Fisher-Yates Shuffle but I'm not sure I've implemented it in the best way* makes it look like a Code Review question, but the fact that you don't understand how to assign individual values of the array to variables makes it doubtful that you've written this code yourself, which is a requirement on Code Review.

Comment: You are correct, I did not write this version of the fisher-yates shuffle myself, though I do intend to use it.  My knowledge of JS is lacking and wanted to make sure I was assigning the variables properly, clearly I wasn't.  The answer provided works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using following code [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w6aw9rbv/):

```
var ranNum1 = ranNums[0];    
var ranNum2 = ranNums[1];    
var ranNum3 = ranNums[2];    
var ranNum4 = ranNums[3];
var ranNum5 = ranNums[4];
```